# Applcation of list-datastructure in python

Tags: python, data-structures

Wish you a very happy and successful day.
I'm studying to the advanced datastructures in python now and I'm trying to find answers with this exercise about handling things with the list. Please help me with this error. Following is the question:

"
Create a program that allows the user to (1) add products to the list, (2) remove items and (3) print the list and quit.

If the user adds something to the list, the program asks "What will be added?: " and saves it as the last item in the list. If the user decides to remove something, the program informs the user about how many items there are on the list (There are [number] items in the list.") and prompts the user for the removed item ("Which item is deleted?: "). If the user selects 0, the first item is removed. When the user quits, the final list is printed for the user "The following items remain in the list:" followed by the remaining items one per line. If the user selects anything outside the options, including when deleting items, the program responds "Incorrect selection.". When the program works correctly it prints out the following:

```
Would you like to
(1)Add or
(2)Remove items or
(3)Quit?: 1
What will be added?: Apples
Would you like to
(1)Add or
(2)Remove items or
(3)Quit?: 1
What will be added?: Beer
Would you like to
(1)Add or
(2)Remove items or
(3)Quit?: 1
What will be added?: Carrots
Would you like to
(1)Add or
(2)Remove items or
(3)Quit?: 2
There are 3 items in the list.
Which item is deleted?: 3
Incorrect selection.
Would you like to
(1)Add or
(2)Remove items or
(3)Quit?: 2
There are 3 items in the list.
Which item is deleted?: 2
Would you like to
(1)Add or
(2)Remove items or
(3)Quit?: 2
There are 2 items in the list.
Which item is deleted?: 0
Would you like to
(1)Add or
(2)Remove items or
(3)Quit?: 4
Incorrect selection.
Would you like to
(1)Add or
(2)Remove items or
(3)Quit?: 3
The following items remain in the list:
Beer
```

**My implementation**:

```
mylist=[]
while True:
    n=int(input("Would you like to\n(1)Add or\n(2)Remove items or\n(3)Quit?: "))
    if n==1:
        a=input("What will be added?: ") 
        mylist.append(a)
    if n==2:
        count=len(mylist)
        print("There are ",count," items in the list.")
        b=int(input("Which item is deleted?: "))
        for b in range(len(mylist)):
            mylist.pop(b)
        else:
            print("Incorrect selection.")
    if n==3:
        print("The following items remain in the list:\n", mylist)
        break
```

And the **programme prints out** like this:

```
Would you like to
(1)Add or
(2)Remove items or
(3)Quit?: 1
What will be added?: Apples
Would you like to
(1)Add or
(2)Remove items or
(3)Quit?: 1
What will be added?: Beer
Would you like to
(1)Add or
(2)Remove items or
(3)Quit?: 1
What will be added?: Carrots
Would you like to
(1)Add or
(2)Remove items or
(3)Quit?: 2
There are  3  items in the list.
Which item is deleted?: 3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ohjelma.py", line 12, in <module>
    mylist.pop(b)
IndexError: pop index out of range
```

I don't know which errors I'm catching atm. Please help me with this!!!
Thanks for your time and efforts!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indices in lists start at 0. So in your example, Carrots is at index 2. Index 3 does not exist and does can not be popped out of the list. The for-loop does not seem to work, you just have to check if the input is smaller than the length of the list. Your logic for `n == 2` should be something like this:

```py
if n==2:
    count=len(mylist)
    print("There are ",count," items in the list.")
    b=int(input("Which item is deleted?: "))
    if b < count:
        mylist.pop(b)
    else:
        print("Incorrect selection.")
```